# MATLAB - 'lib\sift\bin\siftfeat' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: matlab

```
% thresholds used for g2NN test
dr2 = 0.5;

extract_feat = 1; % by default extract SIFT features using Hess' code

if(exist('filesift','var') && ~strcmp(filesift,'nofile'))
    extract_feat = 0; 
end

tic; % to calculate proc time
%C:\python36\Disso\sift-forensic-master
if extract_feat
    sift_bin = fullfile('lib','sift','bin','siftfeat');   % e.g. 'lib/sift/bin/siftfeat' in linux
    [pf,nf,ef] = fileparts(filename);
    desc_file = [fullfile(pf,nf) '.txt'];

    im1=imread(filename);
    if (size(im1,1)<=1000 && size(im1,2)<=1000)
        status1 = system([sift_bin ' -x -o ' desc_file ' ' filename]);
    else
        status1 = system([sift_bin ' -d -x -o ' desc_file ' ' filename]);
    end

    if status1 ~=0 
        error('error calling executables');
    end

    % import sift descriptors
    [num, locs, descs] = import_sift(desc_file);
    system(['rm ' desc_file]);
else
    % import sift descriptors
    [num, locs, descs] = import_sift(filesift);
end

if (num==0)
    p1=[];
    p2=[];
    tp=[];
else
    p1=[];
    p2=[];
    num=0;

    % load data
    loc1 = locs(:,1:2);
    %scale1 = locs(:,3);
    %ori1 = locs(:,4);
    des1 = descs;

    % descriptor are normalized with norm-2
    if (size(des1,1)<15000)
        des1 = des1./repmat(sqrt(diag(des1*des1')),1,size(des1,2));
    else
        des1_norm = des1; 
        for j= 1 : size(des1,2)
            des1_j = des1_norm(j,:);
            des1_norm(j,:) = des1_j/norm(des1_j,2); 
        end
        des1 = des1_norm;
    end

    % sift matching
    des2t = des1';   % precompute matrix transpose
    if size(des1,1) > 1 % start the matching procedure iff there are at least 2 points
        for i = 1 : size(des1,1)
            dotprods = des1(i,:) * des2t;        % Computes vector of dot products
            [vals,indx] = sort(acos(dotprods));  % Take inverse cosine and sort results

            j=2;
            while vals(j)<dr2* vals(j+1) 
                j=j+1;
            end
            for k = 2 : j-1
                match(i) = indx(k); 
                if pdist([loc1(i,1) loc1(i,2); loc1(match(i),1) loc1(match(i),2)]) >10  
                    p1 = [p1 [loc1(i,2); loc1(i,1); 1]];
                    p2 = [p2 [loc1(match(i),2); loc1(match(i),1); 1]];
                    num=num+1;
                end
            end
        end
    end

    tp = toc; % processing time (features + matching)

    if size(p1,1)==0
        fprintf('Found %d matches.\n', num);
    else
        p=[p1(1:2,:)' p2(1:2,:)'];
        p=unique(p,'rows');
        p1=[p(:,1:2)'; ones(1,size(p,1))];
        p2=[p(:,3:4)'; ones(1,size(p,1))];
        num=size(p1,2);
        fprintf('Found %d matches.\n', num);
    end

end
```

Hi all,
I have uploaded the code above for copy-move forgery detection. While running the code there are several errors which I am getting. I have also uploaded the snippet of the error that I am having trouble to fix with. I have also contacted the guy who wrote this code and he replied to me with following message: "You need to compile the third party library in the folder bin/sift accordingly to your operative system.".
I hope to find the solution here.

A snippet of the error

[image]

Comment: The MATLAB code is trying to run an external program: `lib/sift/bin/siftfeat` (using the `system()` command). Does that file even exist? And if so what happens if you try and run it directly (i.e. not with MATLAB)?

Comment: @Justin i contacted the guy who wrote the code and he told me "You need to compile the third party library in the folder bin/sift accordingly to your operative system.". However, i am not sure what he really means.

Comment: Yes I saw that in your original post. But does the siftfeat file exist?

Comment: But either way, the problem here is that you're trying to execute a program (siftfeat) that is external to (and not part of) MATLAB. So we can't help you. You need to create siftfeat or get it working. The guy says you need to compile siftfeat so you'll need to look for the source files for that program. But to repeat, it sounds like siftfeat is nothing to do with MATLAB

Comment: @Justin The siftfeat file exists in the src folder. However, I don't how to compile that in Matlab because it is a C file.

Comment: You don't compile it in MATLAB. It's separate and outside of MATLAB. Compile the C file to generate the executable (nothing to do with MATLAB). Then answer the questions in my first comment!